# jQuery scroll function sticky header should scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using stickyjs.

Due to a wide container I have to scroll to right to see all the datas.

With the sticky header it should scroll within the container, but something brakes. 
If I scroll right, then down then up then down, you'll see the sticky nav (when triggered) loosing the positioning.

Do I need to calculate the offset or something?

I have the feeling that on sticky-start is missing a offset function or something.

```
$('#menu-wrapper').on('sticky-start', function() {
    console.log("Started");
    $('.menu-wrapper').css('left', 'auto');
    $('.is-sticky .menu-wrapper').css('left', -$(this).offset() + "px");

    $('.container-compare').scroll(function() {
        $('.is-sticky .menu-wrapper').css('left', -$(this).scrollLeft() + "px");
    });
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zzn1ffzm/)

Comment: Not sure if it's useful, but I made sticky bar with pure JS and CSS. I just made extra class with `position: fixed` and added or removed it according to current scroll length.

Comment: @Sergey here works fine, I'm using stickyjs as requirement. Ijust need to fix this issue which i guess is related to the offset or position when the sticky header restarts

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot reproduce it. In 61 Chrome it works fine.

Comment: @Sergey if you scroll right the header is still normal, you need to scroll right at the end of COL 8, then down then try to scroll left or up. I mean play with it, it's pretty obvious.

Comment: So. I found the problem. It happens with `left` when we scroll it to top, element which is sticky loses its `left` value. So you should save it somewhere.

Comment: @Sergey could you help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155066/discussion-between-user3699998-and-sergey).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [link](https://jsfiddle.net/jwed2487/) which refers to forked fiddle.
Summarizing things I have changed:

- changed `var offset = $( this ).offset();` into `var offset = $('.container-compare').scrollLeft();`
- changed `$( ".is-sticky .menu-wrapper" ).css( this.tagName + " coords ( " + offset.left + " )" );` into `$( ".is-sticky .menu-wrapper" ).css("left", -offset);`
- replaced `$('.menu-wrapper').removeAttr('style');` with `$('.menu-wrapper').css('left', '0');`